# Add help Page for controllers in Asp.NetCore WebApi Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have multiple controllers in my .netcore application . I want to provide help for each controller . Say e.g. I have two ProductController and ValueController . So when I do a request on browser with "http://ip:port/Product" in that case it should only show help related to Api endpoints added under ProductController only.

I have gone through some of the links but didn't find any thing regarding showing help page per controller only.Thanks

Comment: API help pages were easy in asp.net but in core you have to do something like this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks @Jeff But I don't want to use swagger .Is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: It's honestly not that bad, but I suppose you can create your own auto-generated docs https://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-the-apiexplorer-in-asp-net-core/